# join query in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i am developing a job portal using rails 4.
i have search box where job seeker can search jobs. currently i am able to do it for job title and description , as follows

```
scope :by_name_or_desc,lambda{|search| where(" title ilike (?) or description ilike(?)","%#{search}%","%#{search}%") if search.present?}
```

i want to use the same search box for skills also where seeker can search job using skill. i have skill_ids as a column in my Job model . which is array field. how can i modify above query to do the same.

i also tried doing this ,

```
scope :by_name_or_desc,lambda{|search| where(" title ilike (?) or description ilike(?) or '#{search}' = ANY (skill_ids)","%#{search}%","%#{search}%") if search.present?}
```

Comment: You might consider looking for a gem to do this kind of thing for you. pg_search, for example -- https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search -- and others are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PostgreSQL, you should take a look at [Full Text Search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch.html) feature. Otherwise i recommend you to use [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com) for this kind of stuff. Full-text search is not what RDBMS designed for. With project's growth your approach will be only a headache.

Comment: elastic search is the better option